# GraphLab-Create Module not being installed on Python 3.5 (ubuntu)

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-3.5, graphlab

I used this command:
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/email_address/token/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz

But got this error:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)

I tried downloading the file and installing it manually but that also didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As it was written in previous answers, you should use Python 2.7 instead of the 3.5 one.

Use `pip2.7`, because `pip` may be associated with the Python 3.5:

```
pip2.7 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/email_address/token/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

Comment: How to generate the token?

Comment: @Etisha you'll get your token in an email after the license registration (token = Product key).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the module works only with Python 2.7.x as per [install docs](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html).

Answer (score 0):

here is the link telling you how to change python version in anaconda.
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFCBiP9Gkoo)

Graphlab is not compatible with python3 and you have to change your python version to 2.7. It should work.